# How worthwhile is the Starlingpunk framework currently? Ready for prime time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, 2d-games

Have any of you attempted to work with the Starlingpunk framework for Flash?
It seems almost too good to be true, and I wondered if any of you could speak to its differences from Flashpunk, performance, workflow, or limitations. Thanks for any insight you may have.

http://www.andysaia.com/radicalpropositions/starlingpunk/

Comment: You should rephrase your question to look for concrete answers instead of opinions, what would make you consider it ready for prime time, elaborate if you want feedback otherwise this will likely not get good responses or be voted to close.

Comment: I like this question and would also like to hear the opinions of the community on it. There are quite a few gaming engines out there, however, there are only so much that leverages the GPU ...